# string conversion to const char * problems

Tags: c++, string, char, constants, libcurl

I have this problem that whenever I try to send my post_data1 by libcurls http post it says wrong password, but when I use the fixed expression in post_data2 it logs me in. And when I cout both they are the exact same string..

Can anyone tell me why they are not the same when libcurl put them in the header? Or why they differ before I send them if that is the case.

```
string username = "mads"; string password = "123"; 
stringstream tmp_s;
tmp_s << "username=" << username << "&password=" << password;
static const char * post_data1 = tmp_s.str().c_str();
static const char * post_data2 = "username=mads&password=123";

std::cout << post_data1 << std::endl;  // gives username=mads&password=123
std::cout << post_data2 << std::endl;  // gives username=mads&password=123

// Fill postfields
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_data1);

// Perform the request, res will get the return code
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code?

Comment: I have tried both wireshark to see the packets and the debug mode in Eclipse for look at variables, but couldnt find the error myself.

Comment: why wireshark? The problem is in the code. Use valgrind (if on linux), or appropriate tool (on other platform)

Comment: @BЈовић , That was to see the packets that libcurl posted the server with. So that I could determine what the problem where, since when using cout just before the post, I got the exact same string as I wanted. But somewhere between there and the POST the string changed. Which now makes perfect sence, since I were refering the a place in memory that could be overwritten with random data.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `tmp_s.str()` you get a *temporary* string. You can not save a pointer to it. You have to save it to a `std::string` and use that string in the call:

```
std::string post_data = tmp_s.str();

// Post the data
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_data.c_str());
```

---

If (and only if) `curl_easy_setopt` *copies* the string (and not save just the pointer) you can use `tmp_s` in the call instead:

```
// Post the data
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, tmp_s.str().c_str());
```

But I don't know if the function copies the string or just saves the pointer, so the first alternative (to use a `std::string`) is probably the safest bet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But I have tried the thing you say and I still get the same error.

Comment: since he is working with strings only, he might skip the stringstream entirely and just concatenate it into a string object, thus avoiding the issue.

Comment: @typ0 Are you setting this in a separate function from where you do the `curl_easy_perform`? Or are both calls in the same function? Please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and update your question with it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The first part works like a charm, the second doesnt.

Comment: I thought that it would be rather irrelevant to show the rest of the code, since the problem where related to the string and not the libcurl calls, which turned out to be due to wrong use of pointers. 
And yes the calls are within the same function. And Im not sure what I can tell clearer.
@scones, That seems to work aswell, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
static const char * post_data1 = tmp_s.str().c_str();
```

Is a problem. It returns a string object and then gets a pointer to the internal string data within that object. The string then goes out of scope at the end of that line so you are left with a pointer to ... whatever happens to be in that memory next.

```
static std::string str = tmp_s.str();
static const char* post_data1 = str.c_str();
```

Might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `static` storage specifiers, compile and run.

NOTE: even though `c_str()` result is nominally temporary, it is may also be (and usually is) permanent. For a quick fix, it may work.

Comment: That didn´t make a difference, but the note is also what I found out. Thank you for your time aswell.